# angularjs custom validation on input type="text"

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<section class="col col-6">
   <label class="input">
      <i class="icon-append fa fa-building"></i>
      <input type="text" ng-model="customer.Name" name="customerName" placeholder="Customer Name" required>
      <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.customerName.$dirty && myForm.customerName.$invalid">
         <span ng-show="myForm.customerName.$error.required">Name Required</span>
      </span>
   </label>
</section>
```

How can i implement `custom validation` on it? m applying angularjs validation it works fine but I want custom valuation on this tag. I want user insert only alphabets in this textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ngPattern` directive and provide appropriate regular expression:

```
<input ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" />
```

Comment: @RanaAli That comment is not really helpful in determining the problem. What is your sample input that you expect to pass the validation but it does not or vice versa?